# Can't pass parameter from C to Assembly code

Tags: c, assembly, nasm

From what I understand, when a parameter is passed in a function call in C, the callee can find the first parameter at `[ebp+8]`.
Returning a value through `eax` works for me, reading the right parameter value from the stack doesn't.

Right now I'm just trying to write an assembly function, that can be called from C and returns the same value, that it is being passed.

When I run the following program, it prints `number: 1` to the console, no matter what value is passed into `myFunc`. What am I doing wrong?

---

**assembly.s**

```
section .text
    global _myFunc

    _myFunc:
        mov eax, [ebp+8]
        ret
```

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern unsigned int myFunc(unsigned int somedata);

int main() {
    unsigned int i = myFunc(6);
    printf("number: %i\n",i);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using a Mac, nasm to assemble the code and gcc for C compilation.

**Makefile**

```
macho32:
    nasm -f macho32 assembly.s
    gcc -m32 -o macho32 assembly.o main.c
```

Comment: A little out of my element, but I think you have to set `ebp` in  your assembly function with `push ebp` and `mov ebp, esp` before you can reference the function arguments. Then you'll need to `pop ebp` before you return. See http://unixwiz.net/techtips/win32-callconv-asm.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you refer to argument on stack, by reading from [EBP+offset] - has EBP been set up to actually point at stack? If no, you may have to do that first, conventionally done by:

```
push  ebp    
mov   ebp,esp
```

Only then points EBP to its stacked previous contents, below stacked return address, and below passed arguments.

Comment: And don't forget to `pop ebp` before the return, or I think `leave` can be used as an alternative.

Comment: I assumed, that this was done by the C compiler for me. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You need to setup to access the the parameters first by saving `esp`. This is explained in:

http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc9.html

in section "9.1.2 Function Definitions and Function Calls"

The following works for me

assembly.s

```
section .text
    global myFunc:function

    myFunc:
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp
    mov eax, [ebp+8]
    mov esp, ebp
    pop ebp
        ret
```

main.c

```
#include <stdio.h>

extern unsigned int myFunc(unsigned int somedata);

int main() {
    unsigned int i = myFunc(6);
    printf("number: %i\n",i);
    return 0;
}
```

Assembly & Compilation

```
ericu@eric-phenom-linux:~$ nasm -f elf32 assembly.s 
ericu@eric-phenom-linux:~$ gcc -m32  assembly.o main.c
ericu@eric-phenom-linux:~$ ./a.out 
number: 6
```

I am on a linux machine so I use `elf32`. The use of `macho32` is correct on your Mac.

Comment: `mov esp, ebp` is just to catch anything, that was pushed, but not poped in my assembly code, right? Otherwise esp should be at the same location as before anyways.

Comment: That's done because often the space below ESP is used for variables local to function, and reserved by substracting the amount of needed space from ESP - and later, at end of function, ESP gets restored to its former value that way

Answer (score 1):

Your function should look like this,

```
 _myFunc:

    push    ebp                    ; setup ebp as frame pointer
    mov     ebp, esp

    mov     eax, [ebp + 8] 

    leave                          ; mov esp,ebp / pop ebp

    ret
```

The convention is to use *ebp* to access the parameters, to do so you need to save *ebp* on the stack and make it to point to the new top of the stack. At function exit you should restore *ebp* and *esp*, as the *leave* instruction does.

In *nasm* there is a macro package, **c32.mak**, that can help in supporting the *C calling convention*, these macros are **arg**, **proc** and **endproc**.
Using these macros your code should look like,

```
proc _myfunc
%$i arg

    mov     eax, [ebp + %$i]

endproc
```